# give / lose ground - meaning

Tags: meaning

> **Most stock markets *lost ground* after their recent gains.
>
>   They're not prepared to *give ground* on tax cuts.**

These are all the examples I could dig up in my dictionaries. I don't quite understand the meaning because every dictionary says something different.

Does give/lose ground mean fail completely or lose an advantage or both?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+ground http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+ground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose/gain ground  give/hold ground     are idiomatic and phrasal verbs

1. The expressions *give ground* and *hold*, *stand*, and *shift one's ground*  refer to a  position or viewpoint,   as in an argument , controversy  or struggle.
2. In the phrases "gain ground" and "lose ground" the meaning is 'position or advantage is surrendered / lost' as in an argumennt, competition, and of course  "Price of the Shares" in your sentence.

Comment: I'd agree that they're crystallised verb+noun constructions (like 'catch fire', 'lose face' but not 'lose everything'. These constructions are not usually called 'phrasal verbs' (a term I avoid completely, as being ill-defined).